# Problema con el tamaño del papel de una impresora

Tags: java

Tengo un problema sobre las medidas del papel que tiene mi impresora **Brother QL-800** con ancho 62mm. y alto no definido, ya que el papel es continuo para que el usuario pueda poner las medidas necesarias.

Estoy creando una aplicación en [java](/questions/tagged/java) y **no puedo establecer medidas de alto menores a 62mm.** (que corresponden al ancho), aunque si es posible establecer más de 62mm.

Este es mi código:

```java
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();

Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setSize(175.748031496, 175.748031496);
paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 175.748031496, 175.748031496);

pf.setPaper(paper);

job.setPrintable(new ObjetoDeImpresion(), pf);
job.setJobName("nombre_de_impresion");
try {
    job.print();
} catch (PrinterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

La medida `175.748031496` son puntos y correspone a `62mm`.

Este el objeto a imprimir:

```
public class ObjetoDeImpresion implements Printable {

    public ObjetoDeImpresion() {
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat f, int i) throws PrinterException {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                g2.drawRect(30, 50, 80, 20);
                g2.drawLine(0, 28, 130, 28);

                return PAGE_EXISTS;
            default:
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;        // No other pages
        } //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Creo que la impresora esta detectando como si su alto también fuera 62mm. ya que el papel por el alto es continuo.

¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que expliques que es lo que necesitas que haga tu programa y que es lo que hace mal. Saludos

Comment: Y haz consultado un manual parecido a esto. https://mariusbelin.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/brother-print-sdk-for-android-manual.pdf Supongo que el soporte de la impresora lo debe de proporcionar

Comment: Creo que es una pregunta muy obvia pero ¿por que estas definiendo el tamaño de hoja `paper.setSize(175.748031496, 175.748031496);` igual? El segundo parámetro debería ser una variable. Si lo que quieres es que el usuario defina el tamaño modifica esa parte, si no es eso, pues especifica un poco más la pregunta poniendo ejemplos de los errores que tienes.

Comment: Tengo el mismo valor ya que como comente arriba es la única manera que me deja imprimir asignándole el mismo valor, que es 62mm.

Comment: Ya probaste reduciendo el segundo parámetro de `paper.setSize(175.748031496, 175.748031496);` y el cuarto de  `paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 175.748031496, 175.748031496);`  de manera que se mantengan igual?

Comment: Si ya hice todo eso, al parecer tiene que ver con que el tamaño del papel, que el alto es continuo y no detecta la dimensión del alto, y al no tener un alto definido supongo que la impresora le pone por defecto 62mm.

Comment: Bueno. Desde P-Touch Editor si puedes imprimir en tamaños menores? Tienes los drivers actualizados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba agregando PrintRequest para cambiar los atributos de la impresora:

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
```

puedes ponerlo de esta manera:

```
try {
    job.print(aset);
} catch (PrinterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ¿Como puede con esto el OP "establecer medidas de alto menores a 62mm" de acuerdo a su pregunta? No consideras que deberías especificar más tu respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias esto soluciono mi problema, ya que la impresora no me permitía poner medias aleatorias y por lo tanto ponía las que estaban establecidas por defecto. Al poner el `PrintRequest` le indico a la impresora  que serán nuevos atributos a imprimir.

Comment: Hola tengo el mismo problema con la misma impresora, podrías poner el código de como lo resolviste?