# ¿Cómo marcar el fin de un .txt y cortarlo en la ultima linea al mandarlo a imprimir?

Tags: java, archivo, java-swing

Estoy generando una factura mediante la escritura de un archivo .txt,
el inconveniente es que al finalizar me arroja mucho papel en blanco y quisiera
poder limitarlo a que cuando finalice la ultima linea el papel se corte y no siga imprimiendo espacios en blanco para no desperdiciarlo.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 String path = "C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/Facturas/FacturaCompra.txt";//ruta a donde se va a guardar el archivo
        FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter(path);//crear el archivo

fichero.write(nombreEmpresa());
fichero.write("FACTURA DE COMPRA\n");
fichero.write("-----------------\n");
fichero.write("FECHA: 2023-09-01\n");
fichero.write("No. Factura: 2\n");
fichero.write("Lista de Item....");
fichero.write("quiero cortar el papel justo al llegar aquí");
fichero.close();
```

Comment: ya intentaste ponerle un caracter `\f`?

Comment: Tal vez me equivoque, pero creo estás apuntando en la dirección equivocada, la impresora tiene un tamaño de la hoja que va a imprimir, es ese valor el que tienes que modificar, fijate en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96447/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-el-tama%C3%B1o-de-papel-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-java, si algo te puede servir.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, voy a dar un vistazo.